# How to use curl url for json api integration in android

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio, curl

I have been stuck for many days .
I want to use an api of informedica in my android application .But I did not know how to work with curl
Its curl url is

curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "app_id: 90f10c6a" --header "app_key: 9d23d9250d9f2ee8aa49efda732e4d3d" "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms"

and

Request Url is

https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms

when I try to open request url link i got **authentication parameters missing** error

please guide me !

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Does the basic example from https://developer.infermedica.com/docs/authentication work when you paste in your credentials?

Comment: I could not understand that example . I do not know where I would add my credentials for response and how to make curl

Comment: Simply open up a console and run it there. You have to learn about consoles and curl first, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use Volley to do the cURL request.

```
private void getResponse(){
    String URL = "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("Check Response",response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Check Error","Error");
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return new byte[]{};

        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            map.put("Accept", "application/json");
            map.put("app_id","90f10c6a");
            map.put("app_key","9d23d9250d9f2ee8aa49efda732e4d3d");
            return map;
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES));
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: @Ahmad irfan, you this is the correct answer for you then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my function to get JSON object

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url)
 {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;


}
```

How can i add your code in it?